# Hide link html depending on variable

Tags: javascript, html, flask

i have a flask app running and in an html template i have this

```
<table  style="width:90%">
    <thead><tr><th>Name</th><th>Requested_time</th><th>Description</th><th>Assigned_To</th><th>Status</th><th>Type</th><th>Priority</th></tr></thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for row in rows %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ row.name }}<a style="float: right" href="{{url_for('EditUserRequests', Request_id = row.id) }}" >(Edit)</a> </td>        
            <td>{{ row.Record_Created }}</td>
            <td>{{ row.Description }}</td>
            <td>{{ row.Assigned_To }}</td>
            <td>{{ row.Status_Name }}</td>
            <td>{{ row.Type_Name }}</td>
            <td>{{ row.Priority_Name }}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

i want the link called **Edit**
to be either visible or invisible depending on the string written in the

```
row.Status_Name
```

in each of the table's rows
which might change in each row depending on a database 
how can it be done in **js** ?
if there's an example i'll be thankful

Comment: Why use JS for this? The flask template is perfectly capable and won't risk a rerendering flash as content is dynamically changed.

Comment: i thought js might be the best way? how to do so without it ?

Comment: With an `{% if`

Comment: Lol It was really simple, thank you <3

Answer (score 0):

thanks to  Quentin
this simple made it

```
  <td>{{ row.name }}
                {% if row.Status_Name == "Created" %}<a style="float: right" href="{{url_for('EditUserRequests', Request_id = row.id) }}" >(Edit)</a>
            {%endif%} </td>
```